# Opencart 2.0.1.1: delivery method first time it displays and second time no display

Tags: php, opencart

I altered some coding in checkout/checkout.tpl to hide the shipping details section and take shipping details from the billing details 
it was working perfectly but now delivery method some time it displays and second time no display... don't know what gone to be wrong
Opencart 2.0.1.1

my code goes **checkout/checkout.tpl**

http://pastebin.com/d6AmGPzf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with your code its working fine, i think in some products you might missed to choose the option for shipping required one, choose it as **Yes**

goto>
    **Home>>Products>>edit product(check for all products) data (under data)**
find this and **choose it as yes**
[image]